Can't find token when trying to swap
I have recently created a meme token. I use Phantom Wallet and when I attempt to "swap" SOL to my token(HMT), the token isn't found when searching based on name, symbol, or contract address. This has been occurring since its release on 04/02/2024 and I can't figure out why this would be. I can find it just fine if I search for it using Jupiter. The following are the details of the token:

Name: Hellmo
Symbol: $HMT
CA: 3WmQzxrStJQZ73YG6HdcJAxqC4YJnkJyP3VKoQy4QiEu

The wallet displays the token when it exists in the wallet and it has the correct logo and name. The attached images demonstrate what I am referring to. Why wouldn't Phantom Wallet be able to find it? Any help would be appreciated.


I contacted Phantom and this is the issue:

Phantom has updated the swapper to only show the tokens listed on
Jupiters strict token list. If you don't see a specific token in the
Jupiter swapper, it means you won't be able to swap that token in
Phantom.


I can only assume it has to do with the system Phantom uses to handle their swaps (like Jupiter where you token has to reach a certain liquidity, etc) so I think it would be best to contact Phantom directly. They will most likely be able to give you more insight or resolve the issue.

Thanks for the response. After contacting Phantom, this is the issue:
"Phantom has updated the swapper to only show the tokens listed on Jupiters strict token list. If you don't see a specific token in the Jupiter swapper, it means you won't be able to swap that token in Phantom."
